# is it possible to store single linked list information in NSUserDefaults of iphone

Tags: iphone, linked-list, nsuserdefaults

is it possible to store single linked list information in NSUserDefaults of iphone. If there is an another way to store the information please mention that also

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults can only store standard data types like NSNumber, NSString, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary. You can always implement NSCoding for your linked list class and use Cocoa's standard archiving method to save it to disk.